# Intercept ListView Column disposing

Tags: c#, listview

Environment: C# WinForm Application (Framework 4.0)
Objective: read some data (Ex. column width) from a ListView **just before** the containing form is closed.

I don't wanna read the data **EveryTime** the column size is changed....

If i check Listview.Columns.Count **inside** the FormClosing event, i always find that the list is **ALREADY empty**. 
That means Columns List is getting cleared just before FormClosing event.

How can i get column width (Or other columns-related info) just before the form is closed? 
What is the event i am looking for? I use C#

Thanks in advance guys...you're the best!

Comment: Are you sure you have attached a closing event rather than closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
   protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Event, this will be called before form_closing event.

I have checked your scenario both in `form_closing` and `onclosing` column has the count and you can get the details in both cases . If this does not worked out for you Please post some code so that anyone could help.

Comment: Since even OnClosing wasn't working, i checked again the code and found the issue: On the Custom "Close" button, instead of calling Close() my work mate was calling Dispose() and then Close()... Thanks for your suggestion, it helped me finding the problem.